# Stopping doxygen searching for (and assuming) non-existant variables in source code

Tags: documentation, doxygen

Im using doxygen outside of its design, but well within its capability.  I have a bunch of essentially text files, appended with some doxygen tags. I am successfully generating doxygen output.  However, somehow doxygen occasionally discovers what it assumes to be a variable, and proceeds to document it using surrounding text, causing a lot of confusing documentation. I cant see any direct relationship between these anomalies, only that they're reproducing the same output on each run, and what I can see is at least some are next to a ';' or a '='.

I only want doxygen to document what I've manually tagged.  I am hoping to remove any occurrence of these anomalies, however I cannot alter existing text. I can only add doxygen tags, or alter the configuration file.  Any ideas?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in my particular case, I do not need any automatically generated documentation, only that which I have tagged with doxygen tags, setting

> > EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS  =  *

removes any instance of doxygen "finding" and documenting variables.  This however may remove any ability to find any class declarations, namespaces or functions, however this is acceptable for me.